# How to escape string for SQLite FTS query

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I'm trying to perform a SQLite FTS query with untrusted user input. I do not want to give the user access to the query syntax, that is they will not be able to perform a match query like `foo OR bar AND cats`. If they tried to query with that string I would want to interpret it as something more like `foo \OR bar \AND cats`.

There doesn't seem to be anything built in to SQLite for this, so I'll probably end up building my own escaping function, but this seems dangerous and error-prone. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I've investigated further, and with some heavy magic you can access the actual tokenizer used by SQLite's FTS. The "simple" tokenizer takes your string, separates it on any character that is not in [A-Za-z0-0], and lowercases the remaining. If you perform this same operation you will get a nicely "escaped" string suitable for FTS.

You can write your own, but you can access SQLite's internal one as well. See this question for details on that: [Automatic OR queries using SQLite FTS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860704/automatic-or-queries-using-sqlite-fts4)

Answer (score 11):

The FTS MATCH syntax is its own little language. For FTS5, verbatim string literals are [well defined](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_strings):

> Within an FTS expression a string may be specified in one of two ways:
>
> - By enclosing it in double quotes ("). Within a string, any embedded double quote characters may be escaped SQL-style - by adding a second double-quote character.
> - (redacted special case)

It turns out that correctly escaping a string for an FTS query is simple enough to implement completely and reliably: Replace `"` with `""` and enclose the result in `"` on both ends.

In my case it then works perfectly when I put it into a prepared statement such as `SELECT stuff FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH ?`. I would then `.bind(fts_escape(user_input))` where `fts_escape` is the function I described above.

Comment: One curious thing I noticed when migrating from FTS4 to FTS5, I had to change something of the form `"hyphenated-wor*"` to `"hyphenated-wor"*`. However, would it better to do something like `MATCH ? || '*'`?

Comment: Here's a better `fts_escape` that takes care of hyphened words: `" ".join(f'"{x}"' for x in query.replace("-", " ").split(" "))`

Comment: Polor Beer - No, there are no such function available in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

transform the query to a literal string

```py
def fts_string(str):
    # escape string for SQLite FTS query
    # note: this enforces the order of words
    return '"' + str.replace('"', ' ') + '"'
```

... but that may be too strict, because it enforces the order of words.
for example `"me find"` does not match `find me`

```py
import re
def fts_words(str):
    # escape words for SQLite FTS query
    # https://github.com/hideaki-t/sqlite-fts-python
    pat = re.compile(r'\w+', re.UNICODE)
    return " ".join(map(lambda word: word.lower(), pat.findall(str)))
```

... this extracts words (`\w+`) from the string
and escapes the magic words `AND` `OR` `NOT` by `word.lower()`

```
>>> fts_words('"me AND" find')
'me and find'
```

> I do not want to give the user access to the query syntax

anyway, in some cases, it would be nice to give more power to the user
guarded by rate-limiting constraints like `... LIMIT 1000`

see also

- [Full-text Query Syntax # FTS5 Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_strings)
- [sqlite-fts-python](https://github.com/hideaki-t/sqlite-fts-python) - write tokenizers in Python