# sqlite3_fts5 error when using punctuation

Tags: sqlite, fts5

I have a question string variable that contains the word "Where is my car?"

when I try and run a select on this it crashes.

```
String sql = "Select * from tblHALv2001 WHERE tblHALv2001 MATCH '" + question + "'";
```

> fts5: syntax error near "?"

If I remove the question mark from the question variable then it works. But how can I correct the statement so it doesn't crash?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using C Sharp

Comment: and this is driving me crazy. I have tried every combination I can think of but no matter what, if I use ' or ? in the query text it falls over.

Comment: SQL logic error or missing database
fts5: syntax error near "?"

Comment: see also [How to escape string for SQLite FTS query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971633/how-to-escape-string-for-sqlite-fts-query)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply use any random string with FTS; MATCH expects an [FTS query](http://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax) as its right operand.

You could use double quotes to escape the question mark, but then the tokenizer would ignore it anyway.

Comment: would you be able to give me an example of the double quotes?

Comment: This is how I created my virtual table:

Comment: sql = "create VIRTUAL TABLE tblvHAL2001 USING fts5(question,answer,action,keywordPriority,keyword,keyword2,attach,tokenize=porter)";