# How to escape colon character in search string?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following query, which works perfectly as long as there is no colon `:` character in the search query.

```
search_query =  "http:"
with Session() as session:
    search_query_stmt = text(
        """
        SELECT count(rowid) as count
        FROM post_fts
        WHERE post_fts=:search_string
        """
    )
    count = session.execute(
        search_query_stmt, {"search_string": search_query}
    ).scalar_one()
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: http
[SQL: 
                SELECT count(rowid) as count
                FROM post_fts
                WHERE post_fts=?
                ]
[parameters: ('http:',)]
```

I have tried the following as per [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text)

```
search_query =  "http:"
search_query = search_query.replace(':',  r'\:')
```

Which gives the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) fts5: syntax error near "\"
[SQL: 
                SELECT count(rowid) as count
                FROM post_fts
                WHERE post_fts match ?;
                ]
[parameters: ('http\\:',)]
```

Comment: `http:` as the value of `search_query` works for me without error. The error `no such column: http` suggests that the value is not being escaped, which doesn't match your code.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have edited the question to the bare minimum required. Basically I am stuck between 2 errors - one without escaping and the other one while trying to escape the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution after I got an error for another character (hyphen `-`). The issue was that I was not querying any normal table or view. I was querying a SQLite FTS5 index.

Searching if anyone faced a similar error using FTS5 index, led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525854/sqlite3-fts5-error-when-using-punctuation).

> You cannot simply use any random string with FTS

Read the [SQLite FTS5 Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax) again and found this:

> Within an FTS expression a string may be specified in one of two
> ways:
>
> By enclosing it in double quotes ("). Within a string, any embedded double quote characters may be escaped SQL-style - by adding
> a second double-quote character.
>
> ...

My current working solution is this:

```
search_query = '"' + search_query.replace('"', '""') + '"'
```